# How to build a service worker with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, webpack-5

I'm setting up Firebase Messaging for my website and I need to have a `/firebase-messaging-sw.js` file as a service worker.

I can of course use `importScripts` in it, and have a copy of a firebase config there, but I want to do things in a more smart way.
I want to use typescript, use imports for the firebase config and firebase module itself in order not to load it from the web again and e.t.c.

I don't have a wide experience with webpack, so, maybe the solution is rather simple, but 20 hours of googling led me to nowhere.

Here is what I did:
I created a second `entry` for `firebase-messaging-sw.js`
I added it to the `excludeChunks` setting for `HtmlWebpackPlugin`
I set `output.filename` to generate `firebase-messaging-sw.js` at the website root and with no hash part.

The above parts work as expected. The file is being compiled and saved to `/firebase-messaging-sw.js` . But the code inside it doesn't work.

`сonsole.log` calls that I put there for debug purposes are not being executed.
If I add a script tag for `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to the `index.html`, the code is being executed and works as expected (except for the service worker functionality, of course).
Debugging led me to the fact, that if being added to `index.html`, the code is being called by a function from `chunk-vendors.[hash].js`, which is defined in `index.html` as well. In the case of the service worker, that file, obviously, is not being loaded (as only `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is being loaded) and nothing works, therefore.

Is there any option to tell webpack that I want `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to contain everything that's needed for it to run?

Thank you